# Automapper mapping with IncludeBase failing for abstract generic class

Tags: c#, automapper

I am trying to map reference data entities to dtos, both of which inherit from a generic base class within their own namespace and using an "all purpose" profile to add the mappings. Consider the following code:

```
namespace Dtos
{
    public abstract class ReferenceData<TId>
        where TId : Enum
    {
        public TId Id { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }
    }

    public class ConcreteDto : ReferenceData<MyEnum> { }
}

namespace Entities
{
    public abstract class ReferenceData<TId>
        where TId : Enum
    {
        public TId Id { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }
    }

    public class ConcreteEntity : ReferenceData<MyEnum> { }
}

namespace DtoMapping
{
    internal abstract class ReferenceDataDtoProfile<TDto, TEntity, TId> : Profile
    where TDto : Dtos.ReferenceData<TId>
    where TEntity : Entities.ReferenceData<TId>
    where TId : Enum
    {
        public ReferenceDataDtoProfile()
        {
        }

        protected IMappingExpression<TDto, TEntity> CreateDtoToEntityMap()
        {
            return this.CreateMap<TDto, TEntity>()
                        .IncludeBase<Dtos.ReferenceData<TId>, Entities.ReferenceData<TId>>();
        }

        protected IMappingExpression<TEntity, TDto> CreateEntityToDtoMap()
        {
            return this.CreateMap<TEntity, TDto>()
                        .IncludeBase<Entities.ReferenceData<TId>, Dtos.ReferenceData<TId>>();
        }

        protected void CreateMaps()
        {
            this.CreateDtoToEntityMap();
            this.CreateEntityToDtoMap();
        }
    }

    internal sealed class ProfileForConcreteEntity : ReferenceDataDtoProfile<Dtos.ConcreteDto, Entities.ConcreteEntity, MyEnum>
    {
        public PeriodProfile()
        {
            this.CreateMaps();
        }
    }   
}
```

When I run the application and try to get to the endpoint in question I can see in the debugger that the code of the ReferenceDataDtoProfile class gets executed but then I get the exception that there are no mappings for this objects, specifically:

> InvalidOperationException: Missing map from
>   Dtos.ReferenceData'1[MyEnum] to Entities.ReferenceData'1[MyEnum].
>   Create using CreateMap(ReferenceData'1, ReferenceData'1).

As you can see I am adding the "IncludeBase" method for both ReferenceData abstract classes so I do not understand why I am getting this exception.

On my Web API project I have included the **AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependendyInjection** package **version 7.0.0**.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that `IncludeBase` just specifies that the mapping of the derived objects will inherit the *configuration* of the base objects. However, you still need to create the actual mapping for both the base and derived objects:

```
protected IMappingExpression<TDto, TEntity> CreateDtoToEntityMap() 
{ 
    this.CreateMap<Dtos.ReferenceData<TId>, Entities.ReferenceData<TId>>();
    return this.CreateMap<TDto, TEntity>() 
        .IncludeBase<Dtos.ReferenceData<TId>, Entities.ReferenceData<TId>>(); 
} 

protected IMappingExpression<TEntity, TDto> CreateEntityToDtoMap() 
{
    this.CreateMap<Entities.ReferenceData<TId>, Dtos.ReferenceData<TId>>();
    return this.CreateMap<TEntity, TDto>() 
        .IncludeBase<Entities.ReferenceData<TId>, Dtos.ReferenceData<TId>>(); 
}
```

See [Mapping Inheritance](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Mapping-inheritance.html#mapping-inheritance) for more info.